# PayPal Custom window popup

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to fire a google analytics event to our cart project at the time of the payment transaction start on the Pay now button click on the PayPal popup? Is there any possibility to do that? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `onClick` function. See the [JS SDK reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#oninitonclick).  This will trigger when the button is clicked to *start the checkout.*

However, if you want to trigger an event when the checkout is approved by the payer (final Pay Now action within the popup), use `onApprove`.